# Is there way to find median by only using MaxHeap in nlogn?

Tags: python, heap, median

There is list like a = [1,3,2,4] and I want to find median of [1], [1,3], [1,3,2], [1,3,2,4] (a[0:k],0<=k<=n) 
I know that if I use MaxHeap and minHeap I can solve this in nlogn but I want to know Is there any way using only Max or Min heap to solve this in nlogn colplexity

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806202/whats-the-time-complexity-of-functions-in-heapq-library/38833175#:~:text=The%20complexity%20is%20O(n,O(n%20log%20n).&text=heapify()%20actually%20takes%20linear,is%20different%20than%20calling%20heapq.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but there comments are using Min and Max heap. I want to know way that only using Max or Min heap.